# Increment all cell values in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a script on google sheets to increment all different numeric values in a column by 1, if that cell has a value in it, however currently I've only got a script that increments one cell. I've tried a few different ways to have this function repeat down the rows but I'm just not yet knowledgeable enough to get it functioning the way I want to without changing all of the values in the column to being the same. Any pointers much appreciated. Here's the code for what I want to happen to every row in a column.

```
function increment(targetcell = "A1") {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getRange(targetcell)
  var value = range.getValue()
  range.setValue(value + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adds one to every number in the range you select before running the function.  It skips over blank cells and one that don't contain numbers

```
function addontoallcellswithanumberinarange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rg = sh.getActiveRange();//you select it before running the function
  const vs = rg.getValues();
  const row = rg.getRow();
  const col = rg.getColumn();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (c && !isNaN(c)) {
        sh.getRange(i + row, j + col).setValue(c + 1);
      }
    })
  })
}
```